# How to drop rows in dataframe if a condition isn't met on AT LEAST a specified number of columns

Tags: python, dataframe, subset

I would like to drop rows in a dataframe if the condition isn't met at least 3 times.

i.e if at least 2 columns are >= 10

```
column_1.   column_2.   column_3.   
7           11          15
3           10          9
20          9           15
```

would result in

```
column_1.   column_2.   column_3.   
7           11          15
20          9           15
```

real dataframe contains many columns

Comment: what does if atleast two columns are `>=10` ? every column you have has a value greater than 10

Comment: I think he meant row-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with integers/floats, you can use the following:

```
df['col_count'] = (df>=10).sum(axis=1)
filtered = df[df['col_count'] >= 2] #.drop(columns='col_count')
```

Output:

```
    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_count
0       7      11      15           2
2      20       9      15           2
```

Of course you can add the following line to or discomment it above, to drop the extra column that counts the number of columns for each rows with values >= 10

```
filtered = filtered.drop(columns='col_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,10)*20)
col = df>=10
count = col.sum(axis=1)
df.loc[cout<=3,:]
```